# Php contact form not working well

Tags: php, html, contact-form

So I have built my website and I planned on using a php based contact page to send emails to my email address I made this and I receive an e-mail but no content or summary...
so here is my html:

```
<form action="Php/sendemail.php" method="POST">
<div id="form-inner">

<input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
<textarea class="input textarea" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your message here"></textarea>    

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Send message" id="button">
</div>
</form>
```

and here is my php:

```
$subject = "Contact form submitted!";
$to = 'email@example.com';

$body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;

$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: /Contact.php');
?>
```

I really do not understand why this is happening if you can please help ! Thnaks

Comment: It's because you haven't set/defined/assigned your POST variable(s) to anything.

Comment: You'd might want to remove your email adress.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not geeting the value from the `$_POST` superglobal:

```
$body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;
```

should be:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$body = <<<HTML
$message
HTML;
```

Of course there are other ways to do this like just putting `$_POST['message'];` in the message body but this illustrates how to get the submitted form values.

(You will also want to do things like clean up (i.e. [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/trim), etc) the submitted values and also [defend against header injections](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/228389-preventing-php-mail-header-injections/) as well).